# NyArToolkit for iphone

Tags: iphone

Does anybody have a WORKING copy of NyArToolikit augmented reality port to iPhone? I've read the article http://www.morethantechnical.com/2009/07/01/augmented-reality-on-the-iphone-using-nyartoolkit-w-code/comment-page-2/#comment-380.

Tough I've been unable to figure out the missing parts to make it work. For instance what should be "3DGraphicsView.h" and "3DGraphicsView.m". There's no such file on the code and it seems not to be mentioned on the article text.

Thank you!

Comment: A little progress is finally made. 3DGraphicsView is a copy and paste from EAGLView from Apple code samples (like GLSprite for instance).
Then you need to add the @protocol _DGraphicsViewDelegate on the .h file, and add a delegate property 'id<_DGraphicsViewDelegate> delegate'.

Another think, in order for the project to compile I had to change the compiler version back to 4.0 instead of the default 4.2. That can be changed on the project properties.

Now I'm presented with a empty white view, nothing more. 
Still a long path ahead it seems...

Comment: BTW, I've got the marker image from the pattKanji.pdf file inside the NyARToolkit/data file.

Comment: Now I've got as far as having a twisted white rectangle in the middle of the view. Feel like twitting the pain of discovery.

Comment: Another discovery: the camera component does not work from OS3.0 and up. Could have find about it earlier...

Comment: So, just removed the camera code, let's try to see some AR with a picture of a paper on top of my desk. So far it's throwing and exception on the line:
[nyartwrapper detectMarkerWithIamge:img intoMatrix:ogl_camera_matrix];

Right after reading the image from disk.

Comment: So, no exception but a crapy colorful view is been presented.

Comment: Yup, no luck getting a working copy from the original developer and the code won't work on os3+. Since there's no use for a 2.2- code I'm considering this one dead.

Moving ahead to iOS4 SDK options.

Answer (score 1):

Moving ahead to iOS4 SDK options. NyArToolkit for iPhone (this specific implementation) won't work on OS3+.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check https://github.com/omeryavuz/VRToolKit for augmented reality iphone working demo?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, all you did was fork Benjamin Loulier's Github project: https://github.com/benlodotcom/VRToolKit .  You haven't added anything to what he provides, and now you're just promoting your fork here.

Answer (score 0):

Bug fixed https://github.com/benlodotcom/VRToolKit